# How to format JsonString and put formatted string in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have a Json String having value like given below.

var jsonString = **455: 2.99** **978: 9.98**

This jsonString contains two values one is 455: 2.99 and another is 978: 9.98.

Now I want to push both values in below array where currency is for ex. 455 and desiredJsonString is 2.99.

```
specCurrencySummary.push({ 'field': "currency", 'currencyCode': desiredJsonString});
```

Comment: Why you call it `jsonString`? it's not json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myString = "455: 2.99 978: 9.98";
var values = myString .match(/([0-9.]+)/g)
var rez = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i+=2) {
  rez.push({
    'field': values[i],
    'currencyCode': values[i + 1]
  });
}

console.log(rez);
```

Comment: Could you change the variable name "jsonString"? I think it could be misleading.